Dependency problem while adding onesignal to an existing react native project
I'm integrating OneSignal into my React Native application, but I'm encountering a Firebase dependency conflict error when trying to make a debug build. My React Native version is 0.62.3, Gradle version is 5.5, Google Services version is 4.3.3, onesignal version is 5.2.0 and the conflicting Firebase version is 23.4.1. I'm also using "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.0" and "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^16.5.0" as app dependencies. I've tried removing all Firebase-dependent code and running OneSignal, but the dependency conflict error persists.
The error log I am getting is :-
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[19.0.0, 23.4.99]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.
 
  Dependency failing: com.onesignal:notifications:5.1.8 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@[19.0.0, 23.4.99], but firebase-messaging version was 23.4.1.
 
  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the artifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@{strictly 23.4.1}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.onesignal:OneSignal@{strictly 5.1.8}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.onesignal:notifications@{strictly 5.1.8}
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'react' which depends onto com.onesignal:OneSignal@5.1.8
 
  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dependency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your build.gradle file.

I expected the app to work normally after adding one signal sdk and send push notifications through one signal sdk.

Have you tried to use the latest version?

I am using the latest version of onesignal
